# Android: Python: AndroidViewClient Noob Trouble

Tags: android, python, view, androidviewclient

This is the Alliances screen of my current project:

[image: ActAlliances]

..and this is the view readout using monkeyrunner dump.py:

```
android.widget.FrameLayout id/no_id/1
   android.widget.LinearLayout id/no_id/2
      android.widget.FrameLayout id/no_id/3
         android.view.View id/no_id/4
            android.widget.FrameLayout id/no_id/5
               android.widget.ImageView id/no_id/6
               android.widget.ImageView id/no_id/7
            android.widget.LinearLayout id/no_id/8
               android.widget.LinearLayout id/no_id/9
                  android.widget.TextView id/no_id/10 Alliances
            android.widget.LinearLayout id/no_id/11
               android.widget.TextView id/no_id/12
               android.widget.TextView id/no_id/13
      android.widget.FrameLayout id/no_id/14
         android.widget.TableLayout id/no_id/15
            android.widget.TableRow id/no_id/16
               android.widget.TextView id/no_id/17 Sector: NULL SECTOR
            android.widget.TableRow id/no_id/18
               android.widget.TextView id/no_id/19 Number of Alliances:
               android.widget.TextView id/no_id/20 1
            android.widget.TableRow id/no_id/21
               android.widget.TextView id/no_id/22 Row  Name  Power
            android.widget.TableRow id/no_id/23
               android.widget.ListView id/no_id/24
                  android.widget.RelativeLayout id/no_id/25
                     android.widget.TextView id/no_id/26 1
                     android.widget.TextView id/no_id/27 NULL ALLIANCE
                     android.widget.TextView id/no_id/28 Neutral
                     android.widget.TextView id/no_id/29 10000
```

The following line from my avc_addallc.py presss the New ('+') button in the ActionBar:

```
add = vc.findViewById('id/no_id/12').touch()
```

...which then brings up the AddAlliance dialog:

[image: Add Alliance Dialog]

...with the following view readout:

```
    android.widget.FrameLayout id/no_id/1
   android.widget.FrameLayout id/no_id/2
      android.widget.FrameLayout id/no_id/3
         android.widget.LinearLayout id/no_id/4
            android.widget.LinearLayout id/no_id/5
               android.widget.LinearLayout id/no_id/6
                  android.widget.TextView id/no_id/7 New Alliance
               android.view.View id/no_id/8
            android.widget.FrameLayout id/no_id/9
               android.widget.FrameLayout id/no_id/10
                  android.widget.ScrollView id/no_id/11
                     android.widget.RelativeLayout id/no_id/12
                        android.widget.TextView id/no_id/13 Sector: Helix
                        android.widget.TextView id/no_id/14 Alliance:
                        android.widget.EditText id/no_id/15 Alliance_Name
                        android.widget.TextView id/no_id/16 Leader:
                        android.widget.EditText id/no_id/17 Leader
                        android.widget.TextView id/no_id/18 Political Relation:
                        android.widget.Spinner id/no_id/19
                           android.widget.TextView id/no_id/20 Ally
                        android.widget.TextView id/no_id/21 Rank:   Power:
                        android.widget.EditText id/no_id/22 2500
                        android.widget.EditText id/no_id/23 1234567
                        android.widget.TextView id/no_id/24 No. Players:     Map Score:
                        android.widget.EditText id/no_id/25 100
                        android.widget.EditText id/no_id/26 123456789
                        android.widget.TextView id/no_id/27 No. Bases
                        android.widget.EditText id/no_id/28 8000
            android.widget.LinearLayout id/no_id/29
               android.widget.LinearLayout id/no_id/30
                  android.widget.Button id/no_id/31 Cancel
                  android.widget.Button id/no_id/32 Save
```

The very next line in my avc_addallc.py SHOULD place text in the first EditText (Alliance_Name):

```
etAllc = vc.findViewById('id/no_id/15').type('Legion of Anarchy')
```

which does nothing, but returns this error:

```
130225 21:31:13.023:I [MainThread] [com.android.chimpchat.ChimpManager] Monkey Command: touch down 354 74.
130225 21:31:13.107:I [MainThread] [com.android.chimpchat.ChimpManager] Monkey Command: touch up 364 84.
130225 21:31:16.223:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] Script terminated due to an exception
130225 21:31:16.223:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\code\avc_addallc.py", line 44, in <module>
        etAllc = vc.findViewById('id/no_id/15').type('Legion of Anarchy')
    File "C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86\AndroidViewClient\src\com\dtmilano\android\viewclient.py", line 275, in __getattr__
        raise AttributeError, name
        AttributeError: type
```

Where have I erred? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, verify that you are using [AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) >= **2.3.8**. In previous versions you have to send the strings with whitespace differently.

Then, split the line

```
etAllc = vc.findViewById('id/no_id/15').type('Legion of Anarchy')
```

into

```
etAllc = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise('id/no_id/15')
etAllc.type('Legion of Anarchy')
```

which I guess is your intention. Otherwise, `etAllc` will be always `None`.

Comment: Thank you for your attention to this matter...
The version i have is 2.3.7, which i downloaded just yesterday from https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient
How do i get the 2.3.8 update? Otherwise I'd be happy to make the whitespace/quotation adjustments.

Comment: I downloaded the latest commit (2.3.8) for viewclient.py...
I'm getting the same error, but now for the line:

    etAllc.type('Legion of Anarchy')


...due to making the changes you suggested earlier.

Comment: Realizing that I was asking a lot of a dialog box, I've made the 2nd screen its own Activity. So now one has to select "New" from the Alliances Activity, at which point the AddNewAllc activity comes up with the form. What do i need to do for the Python script avc_addallc.py to recognize the new activity and place data in the form (a process that must be repeated 8 times)?

Comment: Print `etAllc` to verify you are getting what you expect (before etAllc.type()).

Comment: From AndroidViewClient point of view it doesn't matter if it's a new Activity or dialog. It dumps the content of the screen every time you invoke `vc.dump()`.